# Angular UI Select Highlight HTML

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

When I am doing filtering with UI Select the added span tag is appearing as text and not being rendered as html.  I have a pic below to illustrate what I am seeing.  Any thoughts or ideas?   Here is the markup for my UI select if it helps

```
                <ui-select autofocus="autofocus" ng-model="activity.activityCode" theme="bootstrap">
                <ui-select-match allow-clear="false"
                        placeholder="{{scheduler.activityModal.activityCodePlaceholder | translate}}">
                    <div class="activity-code-color" style="background-color:{{$select.selected.color}}">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="activity-code-item">{{$select.selected.title}}</div>
                </ui-select-match>
                <ui-select-choices repeat="act in activities | filter: { title: $select.search }">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="activity-code-color" style="background-color:{{act.color}}">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div class="activity-code-item">{{ act.title | highlight: $select.search }}</div>
                    </div>
                </ui-select-choices>
            </ui-select>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you try to bind html template, you need to use `ngBindHtml` directive:

In html:

```
<div 
    class="activity-code-item" 
    ng-bind-html="act.title | highlight: $select.search">
</div>
```

[API reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)